# Socket programming in Linux by C++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am developing a C++ app in openSUSE 12.3 and one of it's part is responsible to send data to a device via Socket (in LAN). I am using this code

```
int sockfd, portno, n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *printer;    
portno = 9100;  

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket\n"); 
printer = gethostbyname("100.0.69.23");
if(printer == NULL) error("No such device on 100.0.69.23\n");
//set bit set to zero
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *) printer->h_addr, (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, printer-     >h_length);

serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno); 

if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) & serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    {error("ERROR connecting");
           return;
     }

n = write(sockfd, data, datalenght);
if(n < 0) error("ERROR sending command to printer");
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 200);
```

I think the code is correct but the connect function returns -1 and seems that could not connect to the device (printer) . This code was written in openSUSE 11 and was working OK and I could send/receive data to device but when I copy/paste it to new system (openSUSE 12.3) it gives me failure in connecting. I ping result on the specific IP which is in use show that device is reachable via LAN

Comment: how many bytes are you sending to the printer?

Comment: You check for `printer` before it is initialized, and then after. That is no good.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the error that `connect()` is returning? It must have 90% of the answer to your question.

Comment: `datalenght` isnt set, or spelled correctly

Comment: @VladLazarenko : connect returns -1 and the printer is not NULL when connect returns -1.

Comment: @Areff, that's not what Vlad asked. What *error* is connect returning (not what *value*)? connect, like most library functions, returns errors in errno, as the Fine Manual indicates. Always check your errors, for every function you call, ever!

Comment: Type "telnet 100.9.69.23 9100" from a shell prompt. If telnet can't connect, neither will your code.

Comment: An addition to the other answers:
Instead of doing this in low level C, you also might want to consider doing this in C++. More specifically, boost asio might be the choice for you. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html. This will give you less pain with the details and greater stability by hiding the tedious socket layer stuff from you. And IPv6 implicitly.

Unless of course you want to do it the hard way for educational purposes ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider the possibility that `hostent` returned by `gethostbyname` function might have `AF_INET6` address family (in which case it will be IPv6 instead of IPv4 address).

http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname

So you can either use GNU extension function `gethostbyname2` function that will allow you to specify address family.

```
printer = gethostbyname2("100.0.69.23", AF_INET);
```

Or instead you can use [`getaddrinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) function, as `gethostbyname` function is said to be obsolete, by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you are checking for `printer == NULL` before initializing it.  I think you meant the following instead:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket\n");
printer = gethostbyname("100.0.69.23");
...
```

Also the structure of the code seems to indicate that when you want to send a command to the printer you `connect()`, `write()` then `read()`, which is OK if you are only ever sending one command, but suboptimal if you are sending multiple commands.  In the latter case you want to separate the `connect()` from the `write()` as it's fairly expensive to connect so you want to do it just once.

Comment: You right, but the problem is another issue right now , currently I could not connect to the device .after solving the main problem I will change the code as you said and separate the connect and write . and sockfd value is greater than 0 when connect func fails